# Angular-ui-tree: drop a node into the node head, instead of the list

Tags: angularjs, tree, drag-and-drop

I'm using [angular-ui-tree](http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-ui-tree) to create my hierarchy of arbitrary length and depth. I have it working correctly but I would like for node to be added to the children of the node it is dropped on, instead of being added to the current list.

For example, you have your list:

```
- A
- B 
- C 
- D
```

dragging D to B would insert D between B and C or something, instead I want to be able to drop on top of B and have the tree become:

```
- A
- B
  - D
- C
```

Is there a way to do this with angular-ui-tree, or should I use a different module?